# YOLO object detection opencv drawing a lot of rectangles

Tags: opencv, yolo

I have collected images of S9 phones, added labels with labellmg and trained for a few hours in google colab. I had minimal loss so I thought it is enough. I only selected the rectangles where the phone is displayed and nothing else. What I dont understand is, it draws a lot of rectangles on the phone. I only want 1 or 2 rectangles drawn on the phone itself. Did I do something wrong?

```
def detect_img(self, img):
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392 ,(416,416), (0,0,0), True, crop=False)
    input_img = self.net.setInput(blob)
    output = self.net.forward(self.output)

    height, width, channel = img.shape
    boxes = []
    trusts = []
    class_ids = []

    for out in output:
        for detect in out:
            total_scores = detect[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(total_scores)
            trust_factor = total_scores[class_id]
            if trust_factor > 0.5:
                x_center = int(detect[0] * width)
                y_center = int(detect[1] * height)
                w = int(detect[2] * width)
                h = int(detect[3] * height)
                x = int(x_center - w / 2)
                y = int(x_center - h / 2)
                boxes.append([x,y,w,h])
                trusts.append(float(trust_factor))
                class_ids.append(class_id)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x_center,y_center), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 2)
```

When I set the trust_factor to `0.8`, a lot of the rectangles are gone but there are still rectangles outside the phone, while I only selected the phone itself in labellmg and not the background.

[image: Result]

Comment: you should use more complicated training samples and a lot of samples without any S9 phones

Comment: What do you mean with complicated training samples? I used 20 s9 phones and 20 iphones. Do I need 200/300 different images?

Comment: you should use images that show as much variation as possible, to differentiate between an s9 phone and the possible backgrounds and he phone in different sizes (relative to the full size image). I think 200-300 images should be minimum and still it depends on what exactly is visible in the image. e.g. if you have 1000 images of an s9 which a pure black background, you'll still get no better results, since the neural network never learned how real background looks like.

Comment: Oh I understand it now. I thought it is better to use phones with the same background. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function "non maximum suppression" that it removes rectangles which have less score. I put a code for NMS

```
def NMS(boxes, overlapThresh = 0.4):
    # Return an empty list, if no boxes given
    if len(boxes) == 0:
        return []
    x1 = boxes[:, 0]  # x coordinate of the top-left corner
    y1 = boxes[:, 1]  # y coordinate of the top-left corner
    x2 = boxes[:, 2]  # x coordinate of the bottom-right corner
    y2 = boxes[:, 3]  # y coordinate of the bottom-right corner
    # Compute the area of the bounding boxes and sort the bounding
    # Boxes by the bottom-right y-coordinate of the bounding box
    areas = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1) # We add 1, because the pixel at the start as well as at the end counts
    # The indices of all boxes at start. We will redundant indices one by one.
    indices = np.arange(len(x1))
    for i,box in enumerate(boxes):
        # Create temporary indices  
        temp_indices = indices[indices!=i]
        # Find out the coordinates of the intersection box
        xx1 = np.maximum(box[0], boxes[temp_indices,0])
        yy1 = np.maximum(box[1], boxes[temp_indices,1])
        xx2 = np.minimum(box[2], boxes[temp_indices,2])
        yy2 = np.minimum(box[3], boxes[temp_indices,3])
        # Find out the width and the height of the intersection box
        w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
        h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)
        # compute the ratio of overlap
        overlap = (w * h) / areas[temp_indices]
        # if the actual boungding box has an overlap bigger than treshold with any other box, remove it's index  
        if np.any(overlap) > treshold:
            indices = indices[indices != i]
    #return only the boxes at the remaining indices
    return boxes[indices].astype(int)
```